# Computing gradients in extracted Tensorflow subgraph which contains a 'while_loop'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

In some deep learning workflows, it is useful to train a model, extract it out of its graph using `tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants` or `tf.graph_util.extract_sub_graph` so training-related tensors are left out, and then connect the extracted subgraph to other model(s) via `tf.import_graph_def`. In this way, the trained model can serve as a building block in a larger setup.

Often, we'd like to backpropagate through the new, composite model, in order to fine-tune it, optimize the inputs and so on.

However, it appears that one cannot define a gradient through a `while_loop` tensorflow operation in an imported graph, since it relies on 'outer context', an object added into the metagraph's collections (see [TF issue #7404](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7404)). Slightly adapting the example in this Github issue, here's an example of what I am trying to do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
g1=tf.Graph()
sess1=tf.Session(graph=g1)
with g1.as_default():
    with sess1.as_default():
        i=tf.constant(0, name="input")
        out=tf.while_loop(lambda i: tf.less(i,5), lambda i: [tf.add(i,1)], [i], name="output")
        loss=tf.square(out,name='loss')
        graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess1,g1.as_graph_def(),['output/Exit'])

g2 = tf.Graph()
with g2.as_default():
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def,name='')
    i_imported = g2.get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
    out_imported = g2.get_tensor_by_name("output/Exit:0")
    tf.gradients(out_imported, i_imported)
```

The last line raises an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'outer_context'` error.

Tensorflow's solution to this issue is to use `tf.train.export_meta_graph` and `tf.train.import_meta_graph` so the outer  context is copied, but this copies the entire graph, without editting. In this minimal case, the 'loss' tensor won't be removed.

I tried copying the missing context to the new graph:

```
g2.add_to_collection('while_context',g1.get_collection('while_context'))
```

But it doesn't solve the issue.

Is there a way to overcome this limitation or is it an irreparable Tensorflow design flaw?